# PDO Prepared statement Uncaught exception error message

Tags: php, pdo

i am trying to run this PDO Prepared statement

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare(
    "INSERT into email_attachments (email_seq, attachment) 
     values (:email_seq, :attachment) ");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':email_seq' => $admin_email_sequence, 
    ':attachment' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/'.$settings["ticket_files_folder"].'/'.$ticketnumber.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.$at[filename], $at[attachment]
));
```

but I'm getting this error:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /home/integra/public_html/autocheck/support_emails.php:662 Stack trace: #0 /home/integra/public_html/autocheck/support_emails.php(662): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/integra/public_html/autocheck/support_emails.php on line 662`

Comment: What is not clear about the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra **)** inside your execute array, also you have an extra array element (**$at[attachment]**)

Try this code

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("INSERT into email_attachments (email_seq, attachment) values (:email_seq, :attachment) ");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':email_seq' => $admin_email_sequence, 
    ':attachment' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/' . $settings["ticket_files_folder"] . '/' . $ticketnumber . '-' . $currentDate . '-' . $at[filename]
));
```

Answer (score 2):

At the very end of the `:attachment` entry you have a comma instead of what I assume should be a period.

```
.$at[filename], $at[attachment]
              ^-- here
```

This causes the Exception because you have 2 labels in your query, and 3 elements in your array.